# Can I receive notifications about new IP addresses connected to my server?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have a django website deployed on AWS EC2 behind Nginx, without wsgi right now (I'm still in the early stage of development and checking my options).
I've noticed in my nginx access log a few new IP addresses, that are not mine.

Is there any tool available to send notifications about new connections?

I can develop a script for that, but maybe there is a tool already within some wsgi or Nginx.

p.s. I've tried https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can, but do you really want alerts all day long?

You'll be getting alerts all the time from the gazillions of bots that roam the net. That's why you're seeing IP addresses that aren't yours.

You'll need a better definition of 'new connections'.  An alert for SSH connection might be more useful. Having said that, if it's set up correctly you shouldn't need to worry about someone gaining access anyway. If you want to do that check out this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179889/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-alert-when-a-ssh-login-is-successful)

Comment: It's actually not a security concern, but rather an interest about new connections to get some statistics about possible users. So for the first steps and MVP-stage I would be interested in that data.